# Google Script for loop runs entire array each time it is called - looking for

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

In the below code I have a for loop that iterates through array A and then through B but what I cannot figure out is why it is iterating through all 3 of the second array each time the array A is sent to the next iteration. Like A1 -> B1, B2,B3 A2-> B1, B2, B3 etc. I want it to go A1 -> B1, A2 -> B2, etc. Is this possible?

```
function RunAlgo2(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var s=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var gamesArrayList = s.getRangeList(['B5:B6', 'B7:B8', 'B9:B10']);
  var gamesArray = gamesArrayList.getRanges();
  var gameDataList = s.getRangeList(['C5:E6', 'C7:E8','C9:E10']);
  var gameData = gameDataList.getRanges();
  for (var i=0;i<gamesArray.length;i++) {
    for(var j=0;j<gameData.length;j++) {
      gamesArray[i].copyTo(s.getRange('B2:B3'), {contentsOnly:true});
      s.getRange('G2:I3').copyTo(gameData[j], {contentsOnly:true});
      testWait();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue:

- You're nesting for-loops. For each outer loop, all of inner loop will run to completion.

#### Solution:

- Use a single for-loop

#### Snippet:

```
  for (var i=0;i<gamesArray.length;i++) {
//  for(var j=0;j<gameData.length;j++) {
      gamesArray[i].copyTo(s.getRange('B2:B3'), {contentsOnly:true});
      s.getRange('G2:I3').copyTo(gameData[/*j*/i], {contentsOnly:true});
      testWait();
//  }
  }
```